# Message duplication when starting not initialized route (noAutoStartup), then stoping and starting again

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

Is it legal in Apache Camel to start route (and consumer) after it was stopped programmatically?

I have route which is not started automatically (noAutoStartup()). App is also using Spring Boot.

Now, starting this route, stopping and starting again causing to consumers to be duplicated; observed on Hazelcast consumer.

I've tried to add ServiceHelper.startService(consumer) and ServiceHelper.stopService(consumer) with no effect.

I tried to stop route using camelContext.stopRoute(route.getId()) and control bus - same effect.

Camel 2.19.4; 2.20.1

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
It turned out that HazelcastComponent cannot be stopped because it listens to events from Hazelcast and do not unregister this listener during component shutdown.

However, this component is deprecated since 2.20.x, and part of its functionality is available in HazelcastQueueComponent. Finally, HazelcastQueueConsumer in POLL mode respects the fact that service is stopped.